# Matching a text string to a source file

Tags: r

I am trying to evaluate the following text strings:

```
text_example <- structure(list(text_string = c( 
"REALTOR IN DALLAS, TX! CALL NOW FOR SHOWINGS", "BORN IN EL PASO, TX AND CURRENTLY LIVING IN HOUSTON"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I am trying to use a source file to extract the city and state names out of the text string. Here is the source file:

```
city_example <- structure(list(city_ex = c("DALLAS, TX", "EL PASO, TX"), city = c("DALLAS", 
"EL PASO"), State = c("TX", "TX")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I would like the final output to look like this:

```
output_example <- structure(list(text_string = c("BORN IN EL PASO, TX AND CURRENTLY LIVING IN HOUSTON", 
"REALTOR IN DALLAS, TX! CALL NOW FOR SHOWINGS", ""), city = c("EL PASO", 
"DALLAS", ""), state = c("TX", "TX", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

But when I run the following it returns zero results, which should not be the case:

```
output_example <- text_example %>%
  separate_rows(text_string) %>%
  left_join(city_example, by = c("text_string" = "city_ex")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(state)) %>% dplyr::select(text_string, city, state) %>% distinct()
```

What is it about that code that doesn't appear to be working and how can it best be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fuzzyjoin`:

```r
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(text_example, city_example, by = c("text_string" = "city_ex"))
#                                           text_string     city_ex    city State
# 1                   COLLEGE STUDENT LIVING IN HOUSTON        <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
# 2        REALTOR IN DALLAS, TX! CALL NOW FOR SHOWINGS  DALLAS, TX  DALLAS    TX
# 3 BORN IN EL PASO, TX AND CURRENTLY LIVING IN HOUSTON EL PASO, TX EL PASO    TX
```

Your `output_example` suggested that the non-matching row should be the empty string, so you can reproduce that with:

```r
library(dplyr)
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(text_example, city_example, by = c("text_string" = "city_ex")) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(is.na(city_ex), "", .))) %>%
  select(-city_ex)
#                                           text_string    city State
# 1                                                                  
# 2        REALTOR IN DALLAS, TX! CALL NOW FOR SHOWINGS  DALLAS    TX
# 3 BORN IN EL PASO, TX AND CURRENTLY LIVING IN HOUSTON EL PASO    TX
```

... though I personally prefer having `NA` values (an empty string does have value at times) or remove the row (using `regex_inner_join`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a way to do this without fuzzyjoin? Because ultimately what I posted is just a test sample of what will actually be about 20K+ rows to evaluate. That seems to crash my R.

Comment: You are looking for pattern matching. If you want to do a non-regex left join, then your question should be how to extract `"EL PASO, TX"` unambiguously from `"BORN IN EL PASO, TX AND CURRENTLY LIVING IN HOUSTON"`, which takes pattern-matching. That may be less-expensive pattern matching, but (imo) a bit riskier since it appears to be natural language, and extract city/state from natural language sentences has its own level of complexity. I suggest that 20k rows in `text` is one metric, how big is your `city` frame? If it's not huge, then I do not expect long compute times.

Comment: Said differently ... you tried `fuzzyjoin` and it crashed your R? Or you tried something else and it crashed your R?

Comment: I ran it using the actual file I was using. The actual source file has a list of every city and state in the US, so about 30K records. It's evaluating that against about 20K text strings. When I run it using the fuzzyjoin method you posted, it crashes my R.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Batch it, do only 1000 rows at a time. Admittedly this is going to be difficult to do _well_ in a dplyr pipe. (2) `fuzzyjoin::` is using `stringr` under the hood, we can reduce the complexity of regex by using fixed patterns. Try `city_example %>% mutate(city_ex = string::fixed(city_ex)) %>% fuzzyjoin::regex_right_join(text_example, ...)`. I don't know that that will sufficiently reduce the complexity, but using fixed patterns seems like a good thing anyway.